# Is it okay to re-ask a question if you realize it was pretty off-base the first time?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question on Stack Overflow without realizing how far off it was from what I *needed* to ask. Though the new one will be similar, the resulting answer should be pretty different.

I'd simply edit my original question, but I've already accepted an answer, and the answers there won't make much sense once I edit the question (which would be confusing to someone else reading my question in the future while researching an issue they're having).

Comment: Never edit your original question to ask a new one.

Comment: My main worry was that it would seem similar enough that it might come across as an attempt to grind points or something. I guess I was being a little too cautious! Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you should ask a new question.

In addition you should think about referencing your original question and make it as clear as you can that it's a follow up question so that you avoid people thinking you're just reposting the same question again and vote to close it as a duplicate.

So you need to:

- Use a different title - one that more accurately describes the problem.
- Give more detail and specifics of the problem.
- Reference the original (if necessary and only for background).

Comment: If it doesn't make sense to include a reference to the old question in your new one, you can add a comment to your new question as soon as you've posted it.